SeleniumVBA Excel VBA Runtime Error '1' with Chrome
I have an Excel .xlsm file that I use to maintain some stock information.  I use SeleniumVBA to scrape data off of Yahoo and then update tables and charts.  For a long time, this file has worked perfectly.  Then recently it stopped working with Chrome.  When I start up the routine, using the code snippet below, I get the error "Run-time error '1': Error: Driver Download Not Successful".
Set driver = New WebDriver
**driver.StartChrome**  ' <-- Error occurs when executing this line
driver.OpenBrowser


The routine still works fine with MS Edge.
I checked the version of Chrome (Version 123.0.6312.123 (Official Build) (64-bit)) against the version of chromedriver.exe (Version: 123.0.6312.122 (r1262506)) and that seems okay, or is 123 versus 122 a problem?
I have the chromedriver.exe file (and other driver files) in C:\DRIVERS.  I have that folder path in my $PATH environment variable.
I'm not sure what else to look for or try.  I deleted the existing chromedriver.exe file and downloaded a new one.  That did not fix the issue.  Any suggestions are appreciated.
